# Javascript: Prototype object is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

Hopefully someone can help me with this code I have.

**JavaScript:**

```
function myFrame(id){
   if (id) {
      if (window === this) {
         return new myFrame(id);
      }
      this.e = document.getElementById(id);
      return this;
   } else {
      return "";
   }

}

myFrame.prototype = {
    math: function () {
        alert(1 + 1);
    },
    hide: function () {
       this.e.style.display = 'none';
       return this;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="hideParagraph">Hide Paragraph</p>
<input type="button" name="math" onclick="hide()" value="Hide Paragraph" />
<input type="button" name="math" onclick="math()" value="Alert Math" /> 


<script type="text/javascript">

    function math() {
        myFrame("body").math();
    }

    function hide() {
        myFrame("hideParagraph").hide();
    }

</script>
```

The code above works fine but I want to know is there a way not to specify an element.

For example I need to specify **"body"** or some other string value in order for this code to work, else I get a **"is not a function"** error message

```
myFrame("body").math();
```

Is there a way for me to have this code like :

```
myFrame().math();
```

And also still use the **"hide"** method like:

```
myFrame("hideParagraph").hide();
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You specifically wrote code to make that not work.  Get rid of that code, and it will work.

Comment: If the `math` function doesn't require the context of an element, why is it even on the prototype? Either make it `myFrame.math = function` or completely separate it.

Comment: `return "";`.  When you call `myFrame()`, you are returning a blank string (not a new `myFrame` object).  Strings do not have `.math()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your

```
return "";
```

Try:

```
return this;
```

Comment: Close, but not quite.  If he did `myFrame()` and then `return this;`, he'd get `window` because you are not calling `myFrame()` in any context.  For this to work, you'd need to do `new myFrame()` and have it return the newly created object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you understand your problem:

```
function Thing(val) {
  this.val = val;  
};

Thing.prototype.alert = function() {
  alert(this.val);  
};

function start(val) {
  return new Thing(val);
}

start("Hi").alert();
```

You want a class with the alert method and then create a new instance of that class in an outside function.

There are probably many ways to do this. With this setup you can call `start` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your return values.

When you call `myFrame("body")`, the `window === this` inside your function is `true` so then `new myrFrame('body')` is called.  When that happens, you `return this;`. the newly created object.  It's this object that contains the `.math()` and `.hide()` methods on its prototype.

`myFrame().math();` on the other hand.  `myFrame()` fails the `if(id)` check, so it just returns `''`.  A blank string.  Not a `myFrame()` object.  Strings don't have a `.math()` method.

You need to tweak your `myFrame` function like so:

```
function myFrame(id){
    // Determine whether we called 'myFrame()` or 'new myFrame()'
    // In "use strict"; (strict mode), do `if(!this)`
    if (window === this) {
        return new myFrame(id);
    }
    else{
        // In here, this is our new myFrame object
        if(id){
            this.e = document.getElementById(id);
        }

        // This return statement isn't actually needed
        // return this;
    }
}
```

Make sure it *always* returns an object regardless of what parameter you pass.